# Getting error while writing html page from website into CSV file

Tags: python, html, csv, web

When I try to write html of a web page in my_html.html this error pops up. Please guide main how  I can write it successfully.

****ERROR:
File "C:\Users\DRB\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode**
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u21e3' in position 84032: character maps to**

```
import requests

def url_to_file(url, fname= "web_txt.html"):
    response = requests.get(url)
    html_text = response.text
    if response.status_code == 200:
        with open(fname, "w") as r:
            r.write(str(html_text))

        return html_text

    return "Failed to perform its task."

url = "https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/absolute-relative-pathnames-unix/"
print(url_to_file(url))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to open the page in binary mode and save the `.content` of response, not `.text`:

```
import requests

def url_to_file(url, fname="web_txt.html"):
    response = requests.get(url)
    html_content = response.content         # <-- use .content
    if response.status_code == 200:
        with open(fname, "wb") as r:        # <-- open file in binary mode
            r.write(html_content)

        return html_content.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')   # <-- decode content as utf-8

    return "Failed to perform its task."

url = "https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/absolute-relative-pathnames-unix/"
print(url_to_file(url))
```

Prints:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<![endif]-->

...<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7]>
<html class="ie ie7" lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<![endif]-->

...
```

and saves `web_txt.html`